# How do I use Azure Media Services to Dynamically Encode Videos to MP4 using Azure Blob

Tags: azure, video-encoding

I am currently using Azure Blob to store images, and it works great. For a new product I am working on, we are starting to integrate videos. We decided to use Azure Blob to store our videos, and it works great.

We also are saving meta data to the images and videos, and using the Azure Search Service to index the images, and videos, to allow for ease of searching in the new product.

The new problem we are experiencing is the mass amount of file formats being found for upload, are not playing in all devices, and browsers we need to support.

We looked in to Azure Media Services, and found if we encode the videos as H.264 MP4 SD 16x9 using Azure Media Player, it will work in all devices. However, we are now trying to identify how we can easily, and without adding much more time to the user, have the video converted and bound to our search results, to allow for a download link (original video) and play link (converted video).

If anyone knows of a solution, or has a different conversion service that could help, it would be appreciated.

Thank You!